# How to print arrayList to text file?

Tags: java, io, text-files

I want to print the objects within an `ArrayList` (`projects`) to a file as a string. They are currently stored as 'Projects' which is defined in a different class.

When I use `System.out.print` rather than `outputStream.print`, it works fine, and the information appears as expected. As soon as I want it in a file, the file doesn't appear.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class FileController
{
    public static void finish(ArrayList<Project> projects) 
    {
        PrintWriter outputStream = null;            
        try 
        {
            outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("project.txt"));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error opening the file stuff.txt.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Writing to file");

        for(int i = 0; i < projects.size(); i++)
        {
            //System.out.print(projects.get(i) + "," + projects.get(i).teamVotes);
            outputStream.println(projects.get(i) + "," + projects.get(i).teamVotes);

        }

        outputStream.close();

        System.out.println("End of Program");
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to use this constructor, there are easier ones like `new PrintWriter("project.txt")`. There is also **try-with-resources** and **NIO** that should be used nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the file is somewhere, your code has no errors. At least, I don't see any. Maybe you need to call `outputStream.flush()` since the constructor you are using uses automatic line flushing from the given `OutputStream`, see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html). But afaik closing the stream will flush automatically.

Your path `"project.txt"` is relative, so the file will be placed where your code is being executed. Usually, that is near the `.class` files, check all folders around there in your project.

You can also try an absolute path like

```
System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/projects.txt"
```

then you will easily find the file.

---

Anyways, you should use Javas **NIO** for writing and reading files now. It revolves around the classes [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html), [Paths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) and [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html). The code may then look like

```
// Prepare the lines to write
List<String> lines = projects.stream()
    .map(p -> p + "," + p.teamVotes)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

// Write it to file
Path path = Paths.get("project.txt");
Files.write(path, lines);
```

and that's it, easy.